# Find joists in plaster ceiling

Tags: ceiling, joists, plaster

My plaster ceiling is cracking and the advice I’ve gotten is to cover it with dry wall. The issue I’m having is how to locate the joists in the ceiling. Is there an easy way to do this to make sure the drywall is safely secured?

Comment: Adding additional weight is not advisable if the plaster is already cracking. Do you know WHY it’s cracking?

Comment: I think it is just the age of the plaster. I’ve been in the house for two years with no noticeable changes in the ceiling.

Comment: Strip it with one by fours carefully ascertain where joist are by drilling and measuring. Attaching furring to joists with screws long enough to penetrate 1 “. This is much easier than trying to screw a sheet of drywall to the joists. Once it’s all furred yiu can switch back to standard drywall screws and methods attaching to furring https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/39288/drywall-over-plaster-with-furring-strips

Comment: Plaster doesn’t crack because of “age”. It cracks because of movement. If you know the “why?”, then you can address the repair. If you don’t know the “why”, you can over-build and hope for the best. Has there been anything added to the attic? any extra heavy snow load last winter? Anything added outside that could “move/vibrate” the house? Any new work in the street or at your neighbors?

Comment: The plaster ceiling is over 100 years old. My understanding was that overtime horsehair plaster breaks down. Is that incorrect Lee? As I said, in the time we’ve been in the house (two years) there’s been no change in the cracks in the ceiling. The room is on the first floor of a two story house so I also doubt that it has to do with snow on the roof or anything in the attic.

Comment: If you're covering it up, there's nothing to stop you from hammering the crap out of the existing ceiling to find joists, right? (PS, old house joist spacing is nearly guaranteed to be inconsistent, so don't just find a couple and make inferences about spacing/parallel.) On the plus side, you've probably got an actual 2" joist, so they'll be easier to hit. @kris had good advice about strapping... that'll let you make the ceiling flat (or level, if that was important to you) if needed.

Comment: Should have specified that if you opt for the furring strip idea the run perpendicular to existing joists